# Performance issues when automatically putting a large amount of links in spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am using this code snippet to place links to another workbook into my own:

```
Sub legg_inn_lekkjer()
  Dim i As Long

  Call deaktiver

  For i = 0 To 740
    Loktider.Range("C4").Offset(i, 0) = "='[Simulering Arbeidsplan Ovn 3 28h.xls]Lokklegging'!R" & CStr(11 + i) & "C6"
    Loktider.Range("D4").Offset(i, 0) = "='[Simulering Arbeidsplan Ovn 3 28h.xls]Lokklegging'!R" & CStr(11 + i) & "C5"
    Loktider.Range("E4").Offset(i, 0) = "='[Simulering Arbeidsplan Ovn 3 28h.xls]Lokklegging'!R" & CStr(11 + i) & "C16"
    Loktider.Range("F4").Offset(i, 0) = "='[Simulering Arbeidsplan Ovn 3 28h.xls]Lokklegging'!R" & CStr(11 + i) & "C15"
    Loktider.Range("G4").Offset(i, 0) = "='[Simulering Arbeidsplan Ovn 4 30h.xls]Lokklegging'!R" & CStr(11 + i) & "C6"
    Loktider.Range("H4").Offset(i, 0) = "='[Simulering Arbeidsplan Ovn 4 30h.xls]Lokklegging'!R" & CStr(11 + i) & "C5"
    Loktider.Range("I4").Offset(i, 0) = "='[Simulering Arbeidsplan Ovn 4 30h.xls]Lokklegging'!R" & CStr(11 + i) & "C16"
    Loktider.Range("J4").Offset(i, 0) = "='[Simulering Arbeidsplan Ovn 4 30h.xls]Lokklegging'!R" & CStr(11 + i) & "C15"
  Next

  Call reaktiver
End Sub

Sub deaktiver()
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
  ' ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = True 'note this is a sheet-level setting
End Sub

Sub reaktiver()
  Application.EnableEvents = True
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
  ' ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = True 'note this is a sheet-level setting
End Sub
```

It works correctly, but takes quite a while to run. It probably won't be a problem, as I won't need to update the link-addresses very often, but still I wondered if there is a more efficient way to do this, using some kind of relative reference to input the addresses for each column all at once for instance? Quite a lot of googling indicates "no", but I figured it wouldn't hurt to ask.

Answer (score 1):

I can imagine it would be quite slow, your for loop is entering cell values individual in 10 columns for 741 iterations, so around 7.4k cell entries done individually.

You could either create the cell values in an array and then paste that array into the workbook, or more simply enter the expected formulae in the top row and fill down as appropriate.

As an example you could replace:

```
  For i = 0 To 740
    Loktider.Range("C4").Offset(i, 0) = "='[Simulering Arbeidsplan Ovn 3 28h.xls]Lokklegging'!R" & CStr(11 + i) & "C6"
    Loktider.Range("D4").Offset(i, 0) = "='[Simulering Arbeidsplan Ovn 3 28h.xls]Lokklegging'!R" & CStr(11 + i) & "C5"
    Loktider.Range("E4").Offset(i, 0) = "='[Simulering Arbeidsplan Ovn 3 28h.xls]Lokklegging'!R" & CStr(11 + i) & "C16"
    Loktider.Range("F4").Offset(i, 0) = "='[Simulering Arbeidsplan Ovn 3 28h.xls]Lokklegging'!R" & CStr(11 + i) & "C15"
    Loktider.Range("G4").Offset(i, 0) = "='[Simulering Arbeidsplan Ovn 4 30h.xls]Lokklegging'!R" & CStr(11 + i) & "C6"
    Loktider.Range("H4").Offset(i, 0) = "='[Simulering Arbeidsplan Ovn 4 30h.xls]Lokklegging'!R" & CStr(11 + i) & "C5"
    Loktider.Range("I4").Offset(i, 0) = "='[Simulering Arbeidsplan Ovn 4 30h.xls]Lokklegging'!R" & CStr(11 + i) & "C16"
    Loktider.Range("J4").Offset(i, 0) = "='[Simulering Arbeidsplan Ovn 4 30h.xls]Lokklegging'!R" & CStr(11 + i) & "C15"
  Next
```

With:

**Edit -- R1C1 reference system seems to use absolute values, standard cell reference added instead**

```
with Loktider
    .Range("C4") = "='[Simulering Arbeidsplan Ovn 3 28h.xls]Lokklegging'!F11"
    .Range("D4") = "='[Simulering Arbeidsplan Ovn 3 28h.xls]Lokklegging'!E11"
    .Range("E4") = "='[Simulering Arbeidsplan Ovn 3 28h.xls]Lokklegging'!P11"
    .Range("F4") = "='[Simulering Arbeidsplan Ovn 3 28h.xls]Lokklegging'!O11"
    .Range("G4") = "='[Simulering Arbeidsplan Ovn 4 30h.xls]Lokklegging'!F11"
    .Range("H4") = "='[Simulering Arbeidsplan Ovn 4 30h.xls]Lokklegging'!E11"
    .Range("I4") = "='[Simulering Arbeidsplan Ovn 4 30h.xls]Lokklegging'!P11"
    .Range("J4") = "='[Simulering Arbeidsplan Ovn 4 30h.xls]Lokklegging'!O11"
Range(.Cells(4,3),.Cells(744,10)).FillDown
End With
```

This is on a few assumptions, that `Loktider` is a `worksheet` variable you've created, and that you'll be using that specific range as you hardcoded your loop counter.

Comment: Thanks - after some further trial and error I am not certain it is the actual loop / writing to the cells which takes the most time, but actually fetching the workbooks from the server. I am not sure there is a lot that can be done about that, though.

Comment: Within the macro you could open the workbooks, write the formula, and then close them. Links between workbooks resolve faster when the destimation workbook is open.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I am currently doing. Still not ideal, but a bit better.